# How I can debug a stored procedure with a VARRAY parameter?

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql, toad, varray

I have a little trouble to debug a procedure with two VARRAY parameter in TOAD. I have in my DB this VARRAY defined:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.TORDEN_CAMPO as VARRAY(7) of VARCHAR2(13);
```

And now I want to debug a procedure that needs this varray as parameter, but when I execute the debug I have this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 46, column 21: PLS-00316: PL/SQL TABLEs must use a single index
ORA-06550: line 46, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

ORA-06550: line 47, column 20: PLS-00316: PL/SQL TABLEs must use a single index
ORA-06550: line 47, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This is the code that I'm trying to execute:

```
DECLARE 
  PIVTABLA VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVIFGD VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVPERIODO_INICIAL NUMBER;
  PIVPERIODO_FINAL NUMBER;
  PIVPERIODO_EVENTO_INICIAL NUMBER;
  PIVPERIODO_EVENTO_FINAL NUMBER;
  PIVCUENTA VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVENTIDAD VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVMACRO VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVDEPENDENCIA VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVIDPARTIC VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVNIFCLIENTE VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVNOMBCLIENTE VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVNIFGRUPO VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVNOMBGRUPO VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVCODA VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVDIFERIDA VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVTI VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVFILTROANULACION VARCHAR2(32767);
  PIVORDEN_CAMPO BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.TORDEN_CAMPO;
  PIVORDEN_TIPO BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.TORDEN_CAMPO;
  PINREG_INICIAL NUMBER;
  PINREG_FINAL NUMBER;
  XMLFINAL XMLTYPE;
BEGIN 
  PIVTABLA := 'F01';
  PIVIFGD := NULL;
  PIVPERIODO_INICIAL := 201411;
  PIVPERIODO_FINAL := NULL;
  PIVPERIODO_EVENTO_INICIAL := NULL;
  PIVPERIODO_EVENTO_FINAL := NULL;
  PIVCUENTA := NULL;
  PIVENTIDAD := NULL;
  PIVMACRO := NULL;
  PIVDEPENDENCIA := NULL;
  PIVIDPARTIC := NULL;
  PIVNIFCLIENTE := 'F03191871';
  PIVNOMBCLIENTE := NULL;
  PIVNIFGRUPO := NULL;
  PIVNOMBGRUPO := NULL;
  PIVCODA := NULL;
  PIVDIFERIDA := '0';
  PIVTI := '0';
  PIVFILTROANULACION := 'T';
  PIVORDEN_CAMPO := PIVORDEN_CAMPO('F_REPOR','PREF','MREF','IFGD','ID_MOVIMIENTO','ID_GRUPO','CASO');
  PIVORDEN_TIPO := PIVORDEN_CAMPO('D','D','D','A','D','D','A');
  PINREG_INICIAL := 1001;
  PINREG_FINAL := 2000;
  XMLFINAL := NULL;

  BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.PKG_CONSULTA_TRAZABILIDAD.BUSQUEDA ( PIVTABLA, PIVIFGD, PIVPERIODO_INICIAL, PIVPERIODO_FINAL, PIVPERIODO_EVENTO_INICIAL, PIVPERIODO_EVENTO_FINAL, PIVCUENTA, PIVENTIDAD, PIVMACRO, PIVDEPENDENCIA, PIVIDPARTIC, PIVNIFCLIENTE, PIVNOMBCLIENTE, PIVNIFGRUPO, PIVNOMBGRUPO, PIVCODA, PIVDIFERIDA, PIVTI, PIVFILTROANULACION, PIVORDEN_CAMPO, PIVORDEN_TIPO, PINREG_INICIAL, PINREG_FINAL, XMLFINAL );
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

Thanks for your replies!

PD: The lines 46 and 47 in the ORA ERROR are

```
  PIVORDEN_CAMPO := PIVORDEN_CAMPO('F_REPOR','PREF','MREF','IFGD','ID_MOVIMIENTO','ID_GRUPO','CASO');
  PIVORDEN_TIPO := PIVORDEN_CAMPO('D','D','D','A','D','D','A');
```

Comment: Shouldn't lines 46 and 47 read something like `PIVORDEN_CAMPO := TORDEN_CAMPO('F_REPOR','PREF','MREF','IFGD','ID_MOVIMIENTO','ID_GRUPO','CASO');` - i.e., use the defined type `TORDEN_CAMPO` on the right side of the assignment?

Comment: I recall there were some problems with debugging custom datatypes. There are two interfaces for debugging provided by the database. AFAIK only one of them supports custom datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the implicit constructor for collections, i.e. instead of

```
PIVORDEN_CAMPO := PIVORDEN_CAMPO('F_REPOR','PREF','MREF','IFGD','ID_MOVIMIENTO','ID_GRUPO','CASO');
PIVORDEN_TIPO := PIVORDEN_CAMPO('D','D','D','A','D','D','A');
```

you should write

```
PIVORDEN_CAMPO := BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.TORDEN_CAMPO('F_REPOR','PREF','MREF','IFGD','ID_MOVIMIENTO','ID_GRUPO','CASO');
PIVORDEN_TIPO := BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.TORDEN_CAMPO('D','D','D','A','D','D','A');
```

because `BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.TORDEN_CAMPO()` is your `BDD_ACTIVOSEPAREP.TORDEN_CAMPO`-type collections' implicit constructor.